# MailboxImport FailedOther (TooManyLargeItemsPermanentException) - Send/Rece connectors already set to 200MB

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, exchange-2016

I am importing PSTs to Exhange 2016 via PowerShell.

It gets to 100% and then the status is set to FailedOther.

I have to redo the job a number of times adjust the services send/receive size as i read that could be an issue:

```
> Get-TransportConfig | FL MaxReceiveSize,MaxSendSize

MaxReceiveSize : 200 MB (209,715,200 bytes)
MaxSendSize    : 200 MB (209,715,200 bytes)

> get-mailbox user|ft Name, Maxsendsize, maxreceivesize

Name           MaxSendSize MaxReceiveSize
----           ----------- --------------
user Unlimited   Unlimited

> get-receiveconnector | ft name, maxmessagesize

Name                        MaxMessageSize
----                        --------------
Default EX1                 200 MB (209,715,200 bytes)
Client Proxy EX1            200 MB (209,715,200 bytes)
Default Frontend EX1        200 MB (209,715,200 bytes)
Outbound Proxy Frontend EX1 200 MB (209,715,200 bytes)
Client Frontend EX1         200 MB (209,715,200 bytes)
relay                       200 MB (209,715,200 bytes)

> get-sendconnector | ft name, maxmessagesize

Name MaxMessageSize
---- --------------
*    200 MB (209,715,200 bytes)
```

I then set the user to accept bad import items:

```
> Set-MailboxImportRequest -Identity user -Priority Highest -BadItemLimit 100 -AcceptLargeDataLoss
> Resume-MailboxImportRequest -Identity user
```

Checking on the job logs i can see:

```
06/06/2018 02:57:48 [ex1] Source mailbox information:
Regular Items: 0, 0 B (0 bytes)
Regular Deleted Items: 0, 0 B (0 bytes)
FAI Items: 0, 0 B (0 bytes)
FAI Deleted Items: 0, 0 B (0 bytes)
06/06/2018 02:57:48 [ex1] Target mailbox information:
Regular Items: 41299, 9.331 GB (10,018,734,226 bytes)
Regular Deleted Items: 1523, 24.91 MB (26,124,135 bytes)
FAI Items: 40, 79.16 KB (81,055 bytes)
FAI Deleted Items: 0, 0 B (0 bytes)
06/06/2018 02:57:48 [ex1] 11 large items (185.6 MB (194,626,441 bytes)) were skipped.
06/06/2018 02:57:48 [ex1] Copying messages is complete. Copying rules and security descriptors.
06/06/2018 02:57:52 [ex1] Stage: CopyingMessages. Percent complete: 100.
06/06/2018 02:57:52 [ex1] Copy progress: 42258/42258 messages, 9.392 GB (10,084,670,770 bytes)/9.392 GB (10,084,670,770 bytes), 0/0 folders completed.
06/06/2018 02:57:52 [ex1] Fatal error TooManyLargeItemsPermanentException has ooccurred.
```

I don't understand the above as the end and receive at 200MB are well in excess of the total report 11 large items (@ 185.6MB) in their entirety.

Is this because the previous imports had issues with large attachments (at the time of running, the max send and receive sizes were too low) and reporting on older logs?

Or am i missing a setting/step?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to adjust the maxsize on the send and receive connectors.

Get-TransportConfig | FL MaxSendSize,MaxReceiveSize

Get-ReceiveConnector | FL Identity,MaxMessageSize

Get-SendConnector | FL Identity,MaxMessageSize

Comment: Thanks Larryc, confirmed they are all set to 200MB, still same issue though